# Store token replacement values in the database rather than tokens themselves

Tags: 7, tokens

Is there a way to store the token replacement values of tokens put in a form field in the database rather than the tokens themselves?

I have a text field in a custom content type that has a token as default value (using Token Filter), [current-user:uid], so on node creation the replacement value is inserted into the node. In the database, it's stored as '[current-user:uid]', rather than as the replacement value. What is one way of storing the replacement value rather than the token string in that table?

Comment: Your question is so generic that I can only answer it with an equally generic: "Yes, there is a way to do that".

Comment: If there is a way to do that, would you mind giving me a hint what that way is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist of it is to execute [token_replace](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7) in a suitable location. Here's an example.

```
hook_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'page') {
    $replaced_text =  token_replace($node->field_with_replacements['und'][0]['value']);
    $node->field_with_replacements['und'][0]['value'] = $replaced_text;
  }
}
```

Comment: hook_node_presave plus token_replace worked like a charm on various fields, all but the Serial module field (which has a different sort of array, Serial also has problems with Pathauto). Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, serialized data would need to be un-serialized before tokens could be replaced. If you consider this answer "right", you should accept it as the right one.