# Alter label with token

Tags: 7, entities, tokens

I am trying to build a questionnaire that simply replaces (alters) the label of a list field. I am doing so by replacing a token from views (embed) and implementing `hook_form_alter()` in a separate module.

How can I save that value and write it to the database?
I am using an Entity form and a list-field.

This is the snippet I am struggling with, found on [Store token replacement values in the database rather than tokens themselves](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22866/store-token-replacement-values-in-the-database-rather-than-tokens-themselves).

```php
function question_to_label_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'page') {
    $replaced_text =  token_replace($node->field_question['und'][0]['value']);
    $node->field_question['und'][0]['value'] = $replaced_text;
  }
}
```

I am currently trying to run this in a custom module, but I cannot find the right content type for the Entity form. I am using the *Devel* module to find the right array value.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please make your question clearer? What is a "select or other"-field? Which entity form? Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved it by **using a token**, and placed that token (from a view) in a hidden field in that form - thus saving that value.

The same token generated from views - I used to **alter the label** for that question with "hook_alter_form".

A kind of non programmatically way of solving the problem.