# Can't get token replacement to work

Tags: 8, hooks, tokens

I have nearly this exact case but as it applies to Drupal 8: 
 [Store token replacement values in the database rather than tokens themselves](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22866/store-token-replacement-values-in-the-database-rather-than-tokens-themselves)).

I have a content type 'article' with a 'body' field which has been populated with tokens via the Token Filter module.  I believe the code should be something like found here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2043055 but can't get it to work.

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'article') {
    $body = $node->get('body')->value;
    $token = Drupal::token();
    $body = $token->replace($body);
  }
}
```

Thanks for considering, -c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I was unable to actually replace the tokens with the tokens' data in the database, I was able to figure out the ultimate goal which was to replace tokens in the email.  This is the basic code (more details at https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2020-05-03/add-save-send-email-button-to-both#comment-13647867).

````
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);  //load the current node
$token_service = \Drupal::token();  //get the Drupal token service which replaces tokens with tokens' data
$body_field_data = $node->get('body')->value;  //get the "text" (basic data) of the body field
$token_data = array(  //assigns the current node data to the 'node' key in the $data array; the node key is recognized by the Token service
  'node' => $node,
);
$token_options = ['clear' => TRUE];  //part of the Token replacement service; A boolean flag indicating that tokens should be removed from the final text if no replacement value can be generated
$params['body'] = $token_service->replace($body_field_data, $token_data, $token_options);  //sets the 'body' key of the $params array equal to the basic body field data plus replaces the tokens in the body field```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the new value on the body, and save it.

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'article') {
    $body = $node->get('body')->value;
    $token = Drupal::token();
    $body = $token->replace($body);
    $node->set('body', $body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jaypan, really appreciate.  I tried this but it loops and eventually times out (page not found error)...?

Comment: Ahh, of course, I said to call `save()` in `presave()`. That will set it for a loop. You can remove the call to save.

Comment: Shoot.  No dice.  Everything seems to be good but when I check the database, still stored as tokens.  Do you think it might have something to do with metadata?  I've been playing around with using the BubbleableMetadata object I see in the documentation and used in some contrib modules but not getting anywhere.

Comment: Well, I guess part of it depends on what tokens you are trying to replace. You have only passed the first argument to Token::replace() - the string. You didn't pass a second argument. So only global token swaps for things like the current user, or the site name/url will be replaced. Any token that requires a data object will not have any replacement.

Comment: I see.  I am trying to swap node fields of several types (text, date, entity reference).  This inquiry is a follow on to https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2020-05-03/add-save-send-email-button-to-both#comment-13630936 you helped me with a few weeks back (I'm charlie1volley there).  The theory is if I can get the tokens stored as data in the database (like the Auto Entity Label), I will be able to pass the token data in an email.  I'll give this a shot...

Comment: I've tried what feels like a million ways but can't get it to work.  I might be close, but I can't figure out how to post another version of the code?